# Novice ArangoSearch Issue with object property

Tags: arangodb

I'm starting to test ArangoSearch to use in an upcoming feature. I have a nested JSON field that I want to do a token search on a nested field.

`{ip:{dpdm:{description:<text>}}}`

The view is:

```
{
  "writebufferIdle": 64,
  "type": "arangosearch",
  "writebufferSizeMax": 33554432,
  "consolidationPolicy": {
    "type": "tier",
    "segmentsBytesFloor": 2097152,
    "segmentsBytesMax": 5368709120,
    "segmentsMax": 10,
    "segmentsMin": 1,
    "minScore": 0
  },
  "primarySort": [],
  "globallyUniqueId": "h7437427BB0F0/26371461",
  "id": "26371461",
  "storedValues": [],
  "writebufferActive": 0,
  "consolidationIntervalMsec": 1000,
  "cleanupIntervalStep": 2,
  "commitIntervalMsec": 1000,
  "links": {
    "pmconfig": {
      "analyzers": [
        "identity"
      ],
      "fields": {
        "ip.dpdm.version_notes": {
          "analyzers": [
            "text_en"
          ]
        },
        "ip.digital.feature_list": {
          "analyzers": [
            "text_en"
          ]
        },
        "ip.common.Available-Views": {
          "analyzers": [
            "text_en"
          ]
        },
        "ip.pipeline.comment": {
          "analyzers": [
            "text_en"
          ]
        },
        "ip.dpdm.eccn": {
          "analyzers": [
            "text_en"
          ]
        },
        "ip.dpdm.description": {
          "analyzers": [
            "text_en"
          ]
        },
        "ip.dpdm.maturity_comments": {
          "analyzers": [
            "text_en"
          ]
        }
      },
      "includeAllFields": true,
      "storeValues": "none",
      "trackListPositions": false
    }
  },
  "primarySortCompression": "lz4"
}
```

The following query return 58 objects:
`for d in pmconfig filter d.ip.dpdm.description like('% synchronous %') return d`

But the following doesn't return any items:
`for d in v_myView search analyzer(d.ip.dpdm.description in tokens('synchronous', 'text_en'), 'text_en') return d`

I'm sure I did something wrong but it looks right to me.  A pointer to get me going would be appreciated.

Comment: Forgot to mention that for

for d in v_myView return d

does return all of the objects.

Answer (score 0):

I knew I was missing something. Looks like I shouldn't use nested field paths when specifying the view.  All I needed to do was to set the top level field "ip" to the "text_en" analyzer in the view.  All is good now.